# After kernel update windows appear stuck in the corner

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, lxde

After updating with `apt` yesterday, all new windows show up cropped in the upper left corner of the screen. See screenshot. I do not know if this is related. I have set the Desktop Preferences to default, to no avail. Also tried to copy the `/etc/xdg/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` file to `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/`, and `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` to `~/.config/openbox/`, but no joy.

Here is `history.log` from the last two days, although this seemed to start yesteday.

```
Start-Date: 2023-03-07  13:09:34
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Upgrade: realvnc-vnc-server:armhf (6.11.0.47988, 7.0.1.49073), realvnc-vnc-viewer:armhf (6.22.515.47347, 7.0.1.48981)
End-Date: 2023-03-07  13:10:28

Start-Date: 2023-03-08  14:54:17
Commandline: packagekit role='update-packages'
Upgrade: raspberrypi-bootloader:armhf (1:1.20230106-1, 1:1.20230306-1), vcdbg:armhf (1:1.20230106-1, 1:1.20230306-1), raspberrypi-kernel:armhf (1:1.20230106-1, 1:1.20230306-1), linux-libc-dev:armhf (1:1.20230106-1, 1:1.20230306-1)
End-Date: 2023-03-08  14:56:51
```

[image: Desktop screenshot of cropped menu]

Comment: What actual 'apt' commands did you use?

Comment: This time I used the update icon that pops up on the taskbar and clicked "Install Updates". Else, I normally run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you have done (or in which order) but you have done a number of questionable things.

1. NEVER run `apt-get` in interactive mode (you may miss important
   prompts) - use `apt` which is designed for interactive mode.
2. "tried to copy the LXDE-pi/panels/panel file to corresponding
   subdirectory in .config" it is unclear WHAT the "corresponding
   subdirectory" you used may be.

You CAN copy `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` to `.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml` BUT if you do this YOU are responsible for updating. (I do this because it is the only way in Raspberry Pi OS to configure certain settings e.g. `<titleLayout>CIMNLS</titleLayout>`. The tool to do this was removed some years ago.

`.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/` controls the items which appear in the Panel.
NOTE the file says:-
*# lxpanel  config file. Manually editing is not recommended.

Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.*

If it was my Pi I would just **restore from a working backup**.

Your problem appears to be **incorrect Desktop size**. Try again with a different size. (Which size or what the settings do is rather poorly documented.)

You should also remove the file you copied but AFAIK this is ignored/removed if you run `Desktop Preferences/Default`.

Comment: The suggestion of the incorrect desktop size solved it for me. I had also unplugged the HDMI-cable to the TV it was connected too, and that is when the cropping happened. The moment I reconnected the HDMI-cable, all went back to normal. I appreciate the other suggestions too. I will update the question with the directory names.